# Adding html pages on manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im creating a chrome extesion that calls 4 different html pages. The user will interact with a menu(menu.html), and according to the button pressed on the extension will take him to another page.

Do i need to put all my html files on the manifest.json? If yes, how can i add the secondary pages? everything is done but how can i put this together in the manifest?

i have all this files on my folder;

- menu.html
- pageone.html
- pagetwo.html
- pagethree.html
- visual.css

---

```
  {
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "extension test",
     "version": "1.0",         
     "description": "App test",     
     "browser_action": {
     "default_popup": "popup.html"  
  },
      "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png"
       },

  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]   
 }
```

thanks!

Comment: Simply use `<a href="pagetwo.html">` or `location.href = 'pagetwo.html'`

Comment: should i add a <href="pagetwo.html>" in the manifest? where?

Comment: on my menu, the other pages are calling with this onclick=window.open('pagetwo.html','_self')... The action works, but when i try to run as a extension, the button doesnt call anything.

Comment: Sorry, i thought that the problem was on the manifest =/.. Thanks for the help @wOxxOm

Comment: Inline Javascript doesn't work in Chrome extensions. That's why `onclick=window.open ...` won't work. You have to include your Javascript code in a separate file and include it with `<script>` tags.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to supply more detail. As written, we have to make significant assumptions as to what you are asking about. While it appears that the most common assumptions are probably accurate, the question should specify things like how you are displaying the pages (e.g. *popup.html* !== *menu.html*, so we can't assume it is a popup).  The short answer, as you have already gotten, is, using normal assumptions, "No, you don't need to put the HTML file in your *manifest.json*".